# ORB-SLAM2 failed on raspberryPi

Tags: opengl-es, raspberry-pi, ros

After I started roscore and published the data of camera by usb_cam on my raspberryPi 3(module b, with ubuntu mate 16.04), I execute the sample mono by

```
$ ~/catkin_ws/src/ORB_SLAM2$ rosrun ORB_SLAM2 Mono      /home/liuxi/catkin_ws/src/ORB_SLAM2/Vocabulary/ORBvoc.txt /home/liuxi/catkin_ws/src/ORB_SLAM2/my.yaml
```

but it failed and typed

```
Pangolin X11:unable to retrieve framebuff options
```

I did as the tutorials below but no use 
[stevenlovegrove/Pangolin](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin/issues/74) 
what's wrose when I type in "glxgears" to test it output error as

```
Error:couldn't get an RGB, double-buffered visual
```

After reserach I found there may be some wrong with my OpenGL and gpu configurations. But I am really confused about what's exactly the problem, how could I find out it? I will be gratefull if anyone can give me any information.

Comment: Can you provide some links to the tutorials you have mentioned?

Comment: https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin/issues/74

Answer (score 0):

Hy, this may help:

1. There was a bug fix in Pangolin for this error message. (You should update to latest.)
2. When i tried to run OrbSlam2 on a Embedded Board i had the problem that when the Display is not connected this error is also shown.
   (Fixed by forcibly enable Display Port)
3. I also got this error when using Xming (X11 for Windows).